# Can't start Ubuntu

Tags: 13.04, grub2

First of all: I speak Spanish.
So I hope you understand what I am asking:

Recently I successfully installed Ubuntu 13.04.
So after a week, I turn on my computer and [this is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUD7M.png).

This shouldn't appear, It has to appear just when I press F10.
So, when I select Ubuntu in Grub, appears a black screen like this:

[image]

So after this, I can't do anything... <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and <kbd>F10</kbd> doesn't work... So I just turn off my computer the *bad way*.

**What can I do?**

Answer (score 2):

It could be an issue with your MBR, GRUB installation, or something of the sorts - try running Ubuntu using live media so you can download and run [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). Simply put, you can type this in the terminal:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install boot-repair`

You can then launch the utility via the Dash or with the command `boot-repair`. Follow the recommended instructions and I believe it should at the very least do a full reinstall of GRUB2. You *may* be able to perform these same steps using the root prompt in the recovery tool (second boot option) but I'm not sure about that.

Otherwise, it could be an issue with the installation itself, for which you could try to run the diagnostic utilities provided by the recovery tool, or you may have to reinstall.